# Pbxnsip Music on Hold: Streaming shoutcast to RTP on Linux

Tags: ffmpeg, rtp

So we have the PBXNsip PBX server.  We want to hear shoutcast for the Music On Hold (MOH).  They do offer an RTP for the MOH, but the music we want to hear is Shoutcast, and mp3 format.

Is anyone experienced with using mplayer/ffmpeg/ffserver to play the shoutcast stream, and send it to ffserver on a specific port or something so the pbxnsip server can use that port for RTP streaming?

I am not even sure ffserver is what I need but it sounds like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, pbxnsip listens on the RTP port you specify, BUT it only starts listening when you put a call on hold.  Stream via VLC using:

```
cvlc http://[shoutcastip]:[shoutcastport] --loop --norm-max-level=5 --sout='#transcode{acodec=ulaw,samplerate=8000,channels=1,ab=16}:rtp{dst=[PBXNSIP IP],port-audio=[PBXNSIP MOH PORT]]
```

Currently Pbxnsip is having internal issues and they will soon be releasing a new executable; the issue is that the packet length is not the right size for RTP, or so they claim.

This thread may prove useful: http://forum.snomone.com/index.php?/topic/5017-moh-rtp-input/